# Ping/Pong XMPP Not working

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xmpp

I am developing a chat application where I am using the Ping/Pong protocol between  client and server (XEP-0199). I tried to reply with the two methods decribed, the error and the get and didn't succeded till now. I am always getting disconnected by the server for reasons I dont know.

My code is writen in the parseIq() function, when I receive an iq with the next tag "ping", I send the pong, but that is not working.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Please post code or an XML log if you can. For example, if you get disconnected by the server, does it send you an error first? What client library and server are you using?

Comment: @MattJ the server sends me an iq with get type, and I return to him an error that i don't support the ping as dicribed in xmpp protocols, but that isn't working. I am working on JXA Library with OpenFire server .. Any clue?

Comment: What doesn't work? If you're saying the server disconnects you, it sounds like a server bug. Still, it shouldn't be more than a handful of lines of code to implement XEP-0199 in any decent client/library :)